# How to I keep a Material-ui Select open when I click on only one of the items in it

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have been writing a custom Material-UI `Select` dropdown which has an optional text field at the top to allow the user to search / filter items in the `Select` if there were many entries.

I am struggling with how to keep the `Select` open when I click on the text field (rendered as an `InputBase`) and just have the normal behavior (of closing the `Select` when a regular `MenuItem` is selected.

CodeSandbox here : https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-newton-9qsyf

```
 const searchField: TextField = props.searchable ? (
    <InputBase
      className={styles.searchBar}
      onClick={(event: Event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
      }}
      endAdornment={
        <InputAdornment position="end">
          <Search />
        </InputAdornment>
      }
    />
  ) : null;

  return (
    <FormControl>
      <Select
        className={styles.root}
        input={<InputBase onClick={(): void => setIconOpen(!iconOpen)} />}
        onBlur={(): void => setIconOpen(false)}
        IconComponent={iconOpen ? ExpandMore : ExpandLess}
        {...props}
      >
        {searchField}
        {dropdownElements.map(
          (currEntry: string): HTMLOptionElement => (
            <MenuItem key={currEntry} value={currEntry}>
              {currEntry}
            </MenuItem>
          )
        )}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
```

As you can see above I've tried using `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` but to no avail.

Comment: you can make use react-select package may be you are looking for this `https://alligator.io/react/react-select/`

Comment: Select is not good for this usage, because Select children should be the options, and not input filter. Did you consider using material-ui Popover?

Comment: Trying Popover now. Indeed it seems to be a much better solution.

Comment: The multi-select menu will close on selection if the `MuiSelect` or any of its parents are being recreated each render; for example, if they are declared within the body of another functional component. That may not be the case here, I can't quite tell.

Answer (score 4):

check out this codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-paper-9pdnu

You can use `open` prop of [Select API](https://material-ui.com/api/select/)

Comment: Thanks. But yes I was able to do that. What I'm specifically struggling with is how to get the opening and closing behavior working correctly.

Comment: you have to keep `open` as a state

Comment: Hi Nihal. Yes I was aware of that but getting it toggling on the correct events is very tricky. This is what I have so far. Still not the way I want it but getting a little closer. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated - https://codesandbox.io/s/late-smoke-5tyej

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make a controlled open select by providing `open` prop as a react state variable and implementing correct event handlers. To make it controlled you must provide `onOpen` and `onClose` props of the `Select` and make sure the `open` prop stays `true` when the custom textfield is clicked.

One more important thing I had to do was override the default `keyDown` behavior of the `Select` component. If you open up a `Select` and start typing into it, it shifts focus to the select `option` that matches what you are typing. For example, if you `Select` had an `option` with the text *Foobar* and if you start typing *Food and water*, it would cause focus to shift from your custom text input onto the *Foobar* option. This behavior is overridden in the `onKeyDown` handler of the custom textfield

[Working sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-dv1gt)

Edit: even though this worked in the codepen, I had to add `onChange={handleOpen}` to the `Select` as well to get it working on a real browser with React and Next.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `stopPropagation` to make it work

```
// open state
const [isSelectorOpen, setisSelectorOpen] = useState(false)

// handle change
const handleChange = event => {
  const { value } = event.target
  event.stopPropagation()
  // set your value
}

// selector
<Select
  multiple
  open={isSelectorOpen}
  onChange={handleChange}
  input={(
    <Input
      onClick={() => setisSelectorOpen(!isSelectorOpen)}
    />
  )}
  // other attribute
>
  <MenuItem>a</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>b</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>c</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, none of the above worked, but this did the trick to stop closing the Select:

```
<MenuItem
    onClickCapture={(e) => {
         e.stopPropagation();
    }}>
```

You can also change onMouseEnter to change some default styling that comes with using MenuItem (like pointer cursor when mouse enters its layout)

```
onMouseEnter={(e) => {
          e.target.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
          e.target.style.cursor = "default";
    }}
```

In my case i also needed to remove the grey clicking effect that MenuItem makes on click, which is a new object generated in MuiTouchRipple-root, so changing display to none did the trick.

```
sx={{
   "& .MuiTouchRipple-root": {
       display: "none",
    },
 }}
```